# How do I alert my json results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I get these results via php to alert in my ajax alert

```
[{"message_id":"3","box":"0","from_id":"3","to_id":"1","title":"Hello sir!","message":"how are you?","sender_ip":"","date_sent":"","status":"0"}]
```

How do I do `$('#divid').html(message);` ?

I want only specified value from the json array.

Here is the code

```
function showMessage(id){
            var dataString = 'id=' + id;
                    $.ajax( 
                    {  
                        type: "POST",  
                        url: "/inbox/instshow",  
                        data: dataString,  
                        success: function(results) 
                        {

                            if(results == "error")
                            {
                                alert('An error occurred, please try again later. Email us with the issue if it persists.');
                            }

                            if(results != "notallowed" && results != "error" && results != "login")
                            {

                                alert(results);
                                alert(results[0].message);

                            }
                        }
                    });

        }
```

Comment: can we see the code that you use to get the data via ajax

Comment: Edited the question to show my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data = [{"message_id":"3","box":"0","from_id":"3","to_id":"1","title":"Hello sir!","message":"how are you?","sender_ip":"","date_sent":"","status":"0"}] 


$('#divid').html(data[0].message);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j3fgw/)

You might have to parse a JSON string using [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

```
// results is your JSON string from the request
data = jQuery.parseJSON(results);
$('#divid').html(data[0].message);
```

Comment: For some reason it says undefined when I alert(results[0].message); but when I alert(results); it shows data = [{"message_id":"3","box":"0","from_id":"3","to_id":"1","title":"Hello sir!","message":"how are you?","sender_ip":"","date_sent":"","status":"0"}]

Comment: @Darius then you have a JSON encoded **string** that you need to parse using jquery.parseJSON (link that Mahn provided)

Answer (score 4):

If you `ajax` you should include:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

***code***

```
$.ajax( 
       {  
          type: "POST",  
          url: "/inbox/instshow",  
          data: dataString,

          dataType: 'json', // here

          success: function(results) {

           }

.........
```

Including this ***jQuery*** will parse the returned data as `JSON` for you automatically ***(don't need any manual parsing effort)*** and you'll get your result that you're trying now.

Answer (score 1):

use `JSON.stringify()` function

```
var data=[{"message_id":"3","box":"0","from_id":"3","to_id":"1","title":"Hello sir!","message":"how are you?","sender_ip":"","date_sent":"","status":"0"}] ;
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your data broken down by levels:

```
[
    {
        "message_id":"3",
        "box":"0",
        "from_id":"3",
        "to_id":"1",
        "title":"Hello sir!",
        "message":"how are you?",
        "sender_ip":"",
        "date_sent":"",
        "status":"0"
    }
]
```

You would use data[0].message because the first level indicates an array, hence the need of [0] to reference the first and only element, and the second is an object, which properties can be accessed by the object.member syntax.

Answer (score 1):

for debugging purposes

> console.log(data, data.message, "whatever")

You need to open firebug or safari's inspector and look in the "console"